Is there a more concise method to solve the problem of finding tangent lines to curves?
The question is:
If the tangent line to the curve $y=e^x+x$ at point $(0,1)$ is also a tangent line to the curve $y=\ln(x+1)+a$, then $a=$ _______

My method is like this, very cumbersome!
Clear["`*"]
f[x_] = E^x + x;
pt = {0, 1}; k1 = f' /. x -> pt[[1]]
line = y - 1 == k1 x // Simplify
g[x_] = Log[x + 1] + a
k2 = D[g[x], x]
sol = Reduce[{k1 == k2}, x] // ToRules
sol1 = Reduce[line /. sol, y] // ToRules
pt1 = {x, y} /. Thread[{x, y} -> {sol // Values, sol1 // Values}] // 
  Flatten[#, 1] &
Reduce[{y == Log[x + 1] + a, x == pt1[[1]], y == pt1[[2]]}, a]

This problem does not require drawing, just calculate the results of the corresponding parameters.
Is there a more concise method to solve the problem?

This question is similar to: How to make a Line[] with no end?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.  One might supplement Reduce[{1/(1 + x) == 2, Log[x + 1] + a == 2 x + 1}, a] with this  plot:  Manipulate[  Plot[{f1[x], 2 x + 1, Log[x + 1] + a}, {x, -1, 1},  AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotRange -> 2], {{a, 0}, -2, 2}]

@Artes This problem does not require drawing, just calculate the results of the corresponding parameters.

The plot is auxiliary, therein you can find all necessary tools to solve the problem.

@Artes There are two curves in this problem, but the curve you gave only has one. How can we apply it?

This is so obvious that no other hints are necessary, it's been said, the plot is auxiliary.

Method-1

RegionEqual.

Clear["Global`*"];
f[x_] := E^x + x;
g[x_] := Log[x + 1] + a;
line1 = InfiniteLine[{0, f[0]}, {1, f'[0]}];
line2 = InfiniteLine[{x0, g[x0]}, {1, g'[x0]}];
sol = Solve[RegionEqual[line1, line2], Method -> Reduce]


{{a -> Log[2], x0 -> -(1/2)}}.


plotting

Plot[{Callout[f[x]], Callout[g[x]]} /. sol[[1]] // 
  Evaluate, {x, -.9, .6}, Axes -> None, 
 Epilog -> {{Red, line1, line2, Red, PointSize[.02], Point@{0, f[0]}, 
     Point@{x0, g[x0]}} /. sol[[1]]}]


Method-2
Clear[f, g, pt1, slope1, slope2, sol];
f[x_] := E^x + x;
g[x_] := Log[x + 1] + a;
pt1 = {0, f[0]};
slope1 = f'[0];
slope2 = g'[x];
sol = Solve[{slope2 == slope1}]
Solve[{pt1 ∈ InfiniteLine[{x, g[x]}, {1, slope2}]} /. 
  sol[[1]]]


{{x -> -(1/2)}}.


{{a -> Log[2]}}.


Here's a possible easier solution.
f[x_] := Exp[x] + x
g[x_] := Log[x + 1] + a
Reduce[ForAll[{x, y}, y - g[x0] - g'[x0] (x - x0) == y - f[0] - f'[0] (x + 0)]]
(* x0 == -(1/2) && a == Log[2] *)


f[t_] := {t, Exp[t] + t}
tv = (D[f[t], t] /. t -> 0);
tg[s_] := tv  s + {0, 1};
g[t_] := {t, Log[1 + t] + a};
sol = Solve[g'[t] == tv, t][[1]]
asol = Solve[g[t] == tg[t] /. sol, a][[1]]
h = g[t] /. asol
ParametricPlot[{f[t], h, tg[t]}, {t, -1, 1}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.04], Point[tg[t] /. {{t -> 0}, sol}]}, 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions", AspectRatio -> Automatic]



You can check if this does what you want.
x0 = 0; y0 = 1;
f1 = Exp[x] + x;
f2 = Log[x + 1] + a
slope = D[f1, x] /. x -> x0
equationOftangent = slope*x + y0
aSolution = SolveValues[f2 == equationOftangent, a]


Verify
p1 = Plot[{equationOftangent, f1}, {x, -1, 1}, 
          Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[.03], Point[{x0, y0}]}]


p2 = Plot[f2 /. a -> aSolution , {x, -1, 1}]



Your value of a depends on x...? This doesn't make sense.

@NajibIdrissi I did not know that $a$ have to be constant. I see no such mention of this in the question asked. Question just asks to find a value for $a$ which makes $g$ have the same equation as tangent of $f$ at that point, and this what the solution does. If OP can clarify this and say $a$ have to constant, then I will be happy to delete this answer.

According to Najib Idrissi's answer, the code also can be written as follows:
Clear["`*"]
f[x_] := E^x + x; g[x_] := Log[x + 1] + a;
Reduce[ForAll[{x, y}, y - 1 == f'[0] x, y - g[x0] == g'[x0] (x - x0)]]



Why are you posting the same answer as his again?
